# PhpStorm - Exclude forlder from index but not from list

Tags: autocomplete, ide, phpstorm

How to exclude forlder with all files from index and autocomplete, but not project directories list?

[This articles](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-project-structure.html) don't help with problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible right now, [vote for the open feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23537) in YouTrack.